# Find the number of RegEx matches x, duplicate some columns of the dataframe x times + Unicode Error

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, tuples

I am parsing through a multiple-page pdf to extract string data of orders and list of products for each page (aka for each order), before compiling the values to a table using Pandas Dataframe.

| The current output | My desired output |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

As you can see, it is only capturing the first product in each page(aka each order), and moved on.

My code is as following:

```
import re

import pdfplumber
import pandas as pd
from collections import namedtuple

path = "/Users/mymacbook/Downloads/onefolder/123.pdf"

Line = namedtuple('Line', 'PO DeliveryDate PODate ShipTo Barcode Description SMCode Quantity Price')

PO_re = re.compile(r'(\d+\.\d+).+(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})')
ord_re = re.compile(r'(\d+) (.*) (\d{5,6}) (\d+\,\d+) (\d+\,\d+)')
ShipTo_re = re.compile(r'(\w+) (Company Name MM) (.*)')
PODate_re = re.compile(r'\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}')
lines = []

dts = []
with pdfplumber.open(path) as pdf:
    pages = pdf.pages
    for page in pdf.pages:
        text = page.extract_text()
        for line in text.split('\n'):
            if PO_re.search(line):
            #line.startswith('Số'):
                a = line.split()
                b = str(a)
                c = PO_re.search(str(b))
                PO = c.group(1)
                DeliveryDate = c.group(2)
                print(DeliveryDate, PO)
                
            elif PO_re.search(line):
                r = line.split()
                date2 = re.findall(r"\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4}", str(r))
                print(date2)
                PODate = date2[1]
                print(PODate)
                
            elif line.startswith('Name', 30):
                print(line)
                c = line.split(' Name ')
                print(c)
                ShipTo = c[-1]
                print(ShipTo)
                
            elif ord_re.search(line):
                print(line)
                l = ord_re.search(str(line))
                haha = l.group(1)
                Barcode = haha[-13:]
                print(Barcode)
                Description = l.group(2)
                print(Description)
                SMCode = l.group(3)
                print(SMCode)
                Quantity = l.group(4)
                print(Quantity)
                Price = l.group(5)
                print(Price)
            
        dts = Line(PO, DeliveryDate, PODate, ShipTo, Barcode, Description, SMCode, Quantity, Price)
        for item in dts:
            if ord_re.match(line):
                
        lines.append(dts)
          

df = pd.DataFrame(lines)
df.apply(lambda x: pd.api.types.infer_dtype(x.values))
df
```

After converting the current output to a csv file, all the non-English characters got some weird character instead of normal spaces, and all the Vietnamese characters just changed to something totally different, although the output shows no mistakes.

Any solutions on how to fix these problems?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: pdf text sample!

Answer (score 0):

> all the Vietnamese characters just changed to something totally different

If symbols in `df` are ok, then problem is with code that saves csv and is not provided here. Try to add `encoding="utf-8"` argument into your `df.to_csv()` call. If it doesn't work, look up for encoding, that supports your symbols